# Christumatha Nirupanam is available in English?

Tags: translation-request, other-religions, christianity

The book Christumatha Nirupanam is available English translation

Comment: I don't think you need someone specific to tell you where Christianity differs from the Bible. If you want to know have a look at these and use control+f to find what you are looking for: https://infidels.org/library/modern/donald-morgan-contradictions/ https://skepticsannotatedbible.com/EJAT/all.html

Comment: Also, some differences just involve reading commonly known Bible bits. For example, the Bible says "Love thy neighbor AS THYSELF". Christians will often think that means "Love thy neighbor" or "Love thy neighbor and thyself," but that is not what the command says. There is no commandment to love yourself and the separation of spirit and flesh means you can't make the argument people naturally love themselves, as all the evident "self love" is clearly the love of their flesh.

Comment: The commandment is equivalent to "Hate thy neighbor as thyself" and is only concerned with consistently treating yourself and your neighbor not the level of love/hate.

Answer (score 1):

Christumatha Nirupanam has 2 books - Christumatha Saram and Christumatha Chetham.

https://www.academia.edu/14920950/Kristumata_Chedanam_Chattampi_Swamikal_English_Translation this is translation for Chetham.